# how to put a "curl" Api Call into a npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following api call which i want to make when running

```
npm restart
```

The call is:

```
curl -n -X DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/myApp/dynos \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

The point is, that the call will work if I copy paste it into a shell. But if I paste it literally as a script like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node app.js",
  "restart": "curl -n -X DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/mchain-richlist-tracker/dynos \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ -H 'Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3'"
},
```

It returns a script formating error, so I dont know how to input those 2 arguments after the -H

Comment: Take out the \'s in the NPM script.

Comment: Althought it will work the arguments arent being passed as parameters, since it asks me to speiify them manually

Comment: do `curl -- -n -X ....` and check.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty curl: (6) Could not resolve host: -n
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: -X
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: DELETE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an sh script, and calling it with npm. Plus I was missing the auth header
test.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
curl -n -X DELETE https://api.heroku.com/apps/app/dynos -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -H "Authorization: Bearer myAuth"
```

package.json

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "restart": "sh ./test.sh" //script call
  },
```